# Terraform - creating multiple EBS volumes for single instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How would I go about creating and attaching more than one EBS volume to a single ec2 instance? I'm trying to pass a map with the device block variables:

```
block_device_mappings = [
    {
        device_name = "/dev/sdg"
        app_disk_type = "gp3"
        volume_size = "40"
    },
    {
        device_name = "/dev/sdh"
        app_disk_type = "gp3"
        volume_size = "45"
    }

]
```

This is my resource attachment:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count             = length(module.ec2-module.id)
  encrypted         = "true"
  type              = var.app_disk_type
  kms_key_id        = module.datasource-module.data.ebs_kms.arn
  availability_zone = module.ec2-module.availability_zone[count.index]
  size              = var.app_disk_size
  
}
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachment" {
  count       = length(module.ec2-module.id)
  device_name = "/dev/sdg"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume[count.index].id
  instance_id = module.ec2-module.id[count.index]
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs-ephemeral-and-root-block-devices. Especially at `ebs_block_device`. And consider using `for_each` for volumes: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each.

Comment: you might save yourself a headache and use the https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws/latest module it all the resources for an ec2 instance in one definition.